# Is there any way to access c# code or project files in Microsoft visual 2012 using Windows 7 Safe Mode?

Tags: c#, windows, visual-studio-2012

two days ago my laptop fall off from table. I've window 7 installed. My windows is not starting in standard mode I can only get access via safe mode. I was doing a c# project in Microsoft visual 2012 and it was almost completed My problem is that I cannot see project files using safe mode. Is there anyway to access the source code or project so that I can send it to other laptop?
I want to copy my code so that I can complete my project in other system?

Comment: Open My Computer and check if you can navigate to C:\Users\USERNAME\Documents\Visual Studio 2012

Comment: yes i can navigate to it there are two sub folders
 1-Settings and 2- Templates

Comment: Let this be a lesson to 1) backup your computer and 2) use distributed source code control. [GitLab](https://about.gitlab.com/products/) is free for several scenarios.

Comment: @mason what do you mean by that Gitlab can recover my code back?

Comment: No. It might be too late for that. You have to plan ahead. Using a distributed source code control system and pushing your code regularly can prevent you from losing much work. As can regular backups. You can't go back in time, but you can prevent future loss of data by adopting common sense practices.

Comment: @mason thank you for advice ... but for now I'm looking for solution

Answer (score 0):

First, right click on the folder that you want to get files from. Go to security tab, and make sure the admin account you are using has full rights to the folder. They may be not appearing because there is some weird permission things happening.

You may be able to connect to a USB or External HD while in Safe Mode, and then just copy of the files over and put them on another computer with VS 2012. If not, try Safe Mode with Networking and then try to upload to Dropbox/Onedrive.

In desperate times, you can always buy a HD mount device, pull out the HD from the computer, mount with HD mounter on another computer, and copy files over.

Comment: Hi @thatGuy thank you for replying,
but security tab is not showing when I clicked right? I have full rights ...